# How to check if a date entry has been filled in a .csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv, date, datetime, if-statement

I have a simple web scraping python script that writes results to a .csv file. I only want to add an entry if the .csv file does not contain today's date. Currently the writer is not writing at all.

```
with open('results.csv', mode='a') as csv_file:
    write = True
    for line in csv_file:
        if line.contains(date.today()):
            write = False
    if write == True:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writerow([date.today(),mainstream_count,specialist_count])
```

Comment: I would first open the file in read mode, make the determination, and then open in append mode to add the line.

Comment: Actually, I would just check the timestamp of the file

Comment: Thank you, how do I check the timestamp of the file? (new to Python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the modification timestamp on the file before you open it.

```
import csv
import datetime
import os

file_name = "results.csv"

modified = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file_name))

if (modified < datetime.date.today()):
    with open(file_name, mode='a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writerow([date.today(),mainstream_count,specialist_count])
```

Comment: I had to wait until today (the next day) to check if this actually worked, as I couldn't change the modified date obviously. Unfortunately I ran the script this morning and again it didn't write to the file. I've checked with a print log that modified and datetime.date.today() are exactly the same string format, so they should be able to be compared - but no dice.

Comment: `modified` is a `datetime.date` object so the `if (modified < datetime.date.today())` condition is not the issue. What was the modified timestamp on the file? Is it possible that the file was opened before the script was executed?

Comment: Strangely it worked today, so, not sure what happened yesterday, perhaps I somehow opened it. Thank you this solution works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pathlib` to get the file modification time.

```
import time
import pathlib
import csv

file_path = pathlib.Path('results.csv')
modification_time = file_path.stat().st_mtime
current_time = time.time()

# Only write if it wasn't modified in the last 8 hours.
if current_time - modification_time > 60 * 60 * 8:
    with open(file_path.name, mode='a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(
            csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
        )
        writer.writerow([date.today(),mainstream_count,specialist_count])
```

With this logic you'll also want to make sure the file exists before you stat. I'd move this into it's own function.

```
def recently_updated(file_path, hours):
    if not file_path.exists():
        return False
    mtime = file_path.stat().st_mtime
    return time.time() - mtime < 60 * 60 * hours

...

if not recently_updated(file_path, hours=8):
    with ...
```